# How to debug Chutzpah JsonReaderException

Tags: chutzpah

I'm running Chutzpah on a very large file tree of unit tests owned by multiple teams.

While doing a "chutzpah .", I run into this exception:

```
    Chutzpah Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'References[42]', line 61, position 2.
```

I think this is from an invalid chutzpah.json file that someone checked in.
OK, so how can I can figure out where that file is? There are many chutzpah.json files.

I can use process of elimination to search through child directories until I find the ultimate source, but that is slow.

Comment: I eventually decided that running "chutzpah ." on a very large directory is an unwise and inefficient thing to do that is not well-supported by Chutzpah.

Comment: Sorry about the bad experience. If you are still looking for a solution, please post an issue on the github page and I can look to make the error message better